# Programmatically signal LXDE desktop manager to hide its start panel?

Tags: qt5, x11, raspbian, windowing

I'm working on a RaspberryPi with a [3.5 inch LCD screen](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B07N38B86S). I have a Qt 5 based application that operates in kiosk mode without a title bar. The app uses the entire 320x480 screen. I want to hide the LXDE start panel to reclaim the pixels for my app.

I found several posts that detail configuration changes for LXDE to hide the start panel. For example, [here](https://forum.lxde.org/viewtopic.php?t=37420) and [here](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/462458). They provide answers like edit `/etc/xdg/lxsession/LXDE-pi/autostart` and restart.

I'm trying to do the same programmatically. [LXDE has a Wiki](https://wiki.lxde.org/en/Main_Page) but I don't see an API to dynamically configure it.

My first question is, how do tell LXDE to hide its start panel? I'd like the start menu go away, or ensure my app is layered on top of the start panel. I would like to do something like this:

```cpp
MainForm::MainForm(QDialog *parent)
    : QDialog(parent)
{       
    ui.setupUi(this);

    LXDE* lxde = getDesktopManager();
    lxde->hideDesktopPanel();
}
```

If it is not possible to do at runtime, then my next question is, can I run the RPI with only X11? In this case I can remove the desktop manager because I don't need it. Qt can talk to X11 the window manager directly.

PCManFM and friends are pretty much useless on the 3.5 screen, so I don't really care if the solution is to remove the desktop manager.

Comment: Why don't you use  `MainForm w;` `w.showFullScreen();`? With that you don't hide the desktop manager but you make the GUI occupy the entire screen.

Comment: Thanks @eyllanesc. Yeah, that's a nice solution. I am surprised I did not come across it during search (or I read it and it did not sink in). Do you know if we can remove the desktop manager completely?

Comment: 1) I have posted an answer, 2) I am not an expert in desktop manager but I think that question is not appropriate in SO I think it would be more suitable for https://unix.stackexchange.com/, or at least that does not depend on Qt (The Qt tag is irrelevant for that case) but you should focus on the API of your desktop manager.

Comment: Thanks again @eyllanesc. Due to some bad interactions between the Qt Dialog's and the desktop (and probably gaps in my knowledge), I think the desktop has to go. I've begun the experiment to remove Pixel and LXDE. Also see [Desktop still present after removing LXDE?](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/q/106233/112095) on RPI.SE.

Answer (score 1):

A workaround is to use [`showFullScreen()`](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qwidget.html#showFullScreen) that makes the GUI occupy the entire window.

Comment: Thansk @eyllanesc.